# addtoBackStack causing additional blank item before start activity

Tags: android-fragments, back-stack

I have an Activity A. When I click a button I start an Activity B that contains a framelayout that will eventually contain a fragment.

During onCreate of my Activity B I call a method to add fragment F1 to the fragment (fragmentTransaction.add), add it to the back stack and it displays (it's a listview).

When I post my listener back from the fragment to the activity to show an item has been clicked, I repeat the above paragraph, i.e. add the fragment F2, add it to the backstack, let it get displayed. From F2 I might display F3, etc.

This is working fine and for all my items it is fine, and pressing back goes back (F3 -> F2, F2->F1).

However, when I get back to the first fragment F1 and click back, instead of it going back to the first Activity A I get a blank screen, then pressing back again I do get to the start activity A.

What's going wrong?

If it's any clearer, here's the code:

```
private void addFragment(@Nonnull final String fragmentTag,
        final long parentId) {
    GuideListFragment guideListFragment;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    guideListFragment = new GuideListFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fragmentTag", fragmentTag);
    guideListFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    if (fragmentTag.equals(GUIDE_FRAGMENT)) {
        guideItems = dataManager.getAllGuides();
        guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<Guide>(this, guideItems);

    } else if (fragmentTag.equals(TOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
        topicItems = dataManager.getAllTopicsForGuide(parentId);
        guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<Topic>(this, topicItems);

    } else if (fragmentTag.equals(SUBTOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
        subTopicItems = dataManager.getAllSubTopicsForTopic(parentId);
        guideAdapter = new GuideAdapter<SubTopic>(this, subTopicItems);

    }


    guideListFragment.setListAdapter(guideAdapter);
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    guideListFragment.setListAdapter(guideAdapter);

    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.guidelist_container, guideListFragment,
            fragmentTag);

    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

and here's the callback from my list fragment, which essentially adds the next level:

```
public void onGuideSelected(long id, @Nonnull final String fragmentTag) {
    if (fragmentTag.equals(GUIDE_FRAGMENT)) {
        addFragment(TOPIC_FRAGMENT, id);
    } else if (fragmentTag.equals(TOPIC_FRAGMENT)) {
        addFragment(SUBTOPIC_FRAGMENT, id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is expected behaviour. When I add the first page the activity is actually a blank page with a framelayout so adding backstack takes you back to this page.